# React Native + Expo IAP

Tags: react-native, expo, in-app-purchase, react-native-iap

How can I implement IAP with Expo?

I have seen RevenueCat, but I don't know if I will be able to get data from backend (validate payments) and be able to get subscription data. Thanks

I have tried react-native-iap and I didn't get it to work, I also tried expo-in-app-payments and it seems to be working, but when uploading an .aab file I get adverted that it is not updated and I need to update the billing library. https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/deprecation-faq